# Обновление данных в бд ларавел, на основании другой бд?

Tags: php, laravel

Подскажите как можно в приложении на laravel получить и обновить данные в таблице, на основании данных таблицы из другой бд. Подключение к другой бд прописала. Дальше я прописала в модели которую хочу обновлять данными из другой бд, я прописала

```
protected $connection = 'mysql2';
```

и дальше я хочу получить данные из другой бд, сохранить и обновить свою таблицу. Внизу набрасала получение и сохранения данных (если это конечно правильно), а как прописать обновить  данные в моей таблице на полученные?

```
 protected static function boot()
    {
    $data = DB::connection('mysql2')->table('rc')->select('id', 'name')->get();
    $data->save();


    static::created();
    self::updated();
    parent::boot();

    }
```

Comment: Сделать 2 модели. В одной из них прописать `$connection = 'mysql2'`. Если таблицы полностью одинаковые, то одну модель можно отнаследовать от другой во избежание дублирование кода. Затем пройтись по типу `Model_2::query()->cursor() as $model_2`, находить соответствующую модель в другой БД `$model_1 = Model_1::firstOrNew(['id' => $model_2->getKey(), $model_1->toArray()]); $model_1->save()`. Как-то так. Только не засовывайте это в boot() - это для другого предназначено. Хотя напишите конкретнее

Comment: Смысл какой: мне нужно подключаться к сторонней бд (на sql) и забирать данные для свой бд и вставлять полученные данные в свою таблицу . То есть когда в сторонней бд добавляют данные они должны попасть в мою бд, а дальше я их уже использую в своем проекте на laravel.